# Aircrack-ng won't install

Tags: 12.04, aircrack-ng

I am trying to install aircrack-ng but I keep getting this error when I run make.

```
make -C src all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/development/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc1/src'
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30       -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude  wpaclean.o osdep/radiotap/radiotap.o -o wpaclean -Losdep -losdep -lnl-genl-3 -lnl-3  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnl-genl-3
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [wpaclean] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/development/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc1/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have run apt-get install libssl-dev build-essencial and I have changed the line CFLAGS ?= -g -W -Wall -Werror -O3 to CFLAGS ?= -g -W -Wall -O3, so I don't know what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

That's linking error about missing lib:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnl-genl-3
```

1. As aircrack-ng is in repository, install build dependencies using:

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep aircrack-ng
   ```
2. Carry on installing missing ones which are not checked by `./configure`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libnl-genl-3-dev
   ```

You can use Synaptic to search for missing development lib, most have `lib` prefix and `-dev` suffix.

Comment: I tried the first command and I got an error saying apt-get couldn't find the package.

Comment: @EliasLawson-Fox, Sorry it seems aircrack-ng dropped in 12.04 release. http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=aircrack-ng&searchon=names . Try use second to resolve them one by one.